# How can I handle excution flow of nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
var total = 0;

setTimeout(function(){
    total = 5000;
},5000);
pa = (total*40)/100;
console.log("Pa :"+pa);
```

Output :

```
Pa : 0
```

How to get proper value of pa. I think callback function.....
But don't know more about it Please help me 
[Information : I use timer in above example because I want to retrieve some value from another function and it take 5 second to return.]
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Would highly recommend you take a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module for something like this.I wrote some sample code using this, and it returned 2000.

```
var async = require ('async');

var total = 0;

async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        setTimeout(function(){
            total = 5000;
            callback(null);
        },5000);

    },
    function(callback){
        pa = (total*40)/100;
        callback(null);
    },
],
//Now the other tasks are completed.
function(err, results){
    console.log("Pa :"+pa);
});
```

Comment: Don't use async for something so simple -.-

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you use callbacks

```
var total = 0

setTimeout(doLater, 5000)

function doLater() {
    total = 5000
    next()
}

function next() {
    pa = (total*40)/100;
    console.log("Pa :"+pa);
}
```